# seasonal Mann-Kendall; daily vs monthly results

Tags: hypothesis-testing, test-for-trend

I am using https://pypi.org/project/pymannkendall/ in order to get trends for hydrometeorological data such as discharge, air temperature, etc. they have a strong seasonality. when I apply the same dataset on monthly basis I get different results (slope and p-values) than when I use daily values aggregated with the same original data.
any hint why that can be? what would you suggest instead?